# SSRS column grouping not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Here is my dataset result from SQL Server 2017:

[image]

Here is what my SSRS report design looks like:

[image]

Starting at the top,

```
The 1st Expr =IIF(Fields!TermType.Value = "New", "Written Premium - New", "Written Premium - Renew")

The 2nd Expr =IIf(InStr(Fields!Year.Value, (" - Total New")) > 0, LEFT(Fields!Year.Value, 4), 
    IIf(InStr(Fields!Year.Value, (" - Total Renew")) > 0, LEFT(Fields!Year.Value, 4),
        Nothing
    )
)

The 3rd & 4th Expr are duplicated:  
=IIf(InStr(Fields!Year.Value, (" - Total New")) > 0, FormatNumber(Fields!WrittenPremium.Value, 2),
    IIf(InStr(Fields!Year.Value, (" - Total Renew")) > 0, FormatNumber(Fields!WrittenPremium.Value, 2),
    Nothing)
)
```

Then finally here is the SSRS report layout with the extra column for each year:

[image]

My question is, why do I have blank column and how can I display the results without the blank column. Sorry for the length of this post. Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have two column grouping levels.  Most likely the blank column is the subtotal for one of the groups.  Try it with just a single column group instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wes.  Unfortunately that was not the case as I don't have a subtotal on either column group.

Comment: We think it's because there are 2 possible values in the TermType column which is one of the column groups but I don't know how to exclude it if not populated.

Comment: Add a dataset or matrix filter to exclude where TermType is blank.  Obviously that would have the effect of removing the data for that record as well.

Comment: Hey Wes, do I add a matrix filter to the tablix?

Comment: Try just changing the dataset query to ignore NULL in the RN column. `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE RN IS NOT NILL` . If you can't do that , right-click the dataset, then properties then add a filter to do the same. If that does not work then check your column group's grouping properties.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the reply.  I tried all 3 and unfortunately no change.  In the first suggestion I changed the RN to 0 when NULL but I do need the values in the row where RN = 0 or NULL.  The last suggestion only showed a SORT of the column selected in the Column Group itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's happening...

You are 'correcting' the data in the rows where RN is null but you are still grouping by the field's original value.

So, whilst `2017 - Total New` will be presented as `2017`, the column group is using the raw data (`2017 - Total New`).

You have two options.

1. Change the column group's grouping expression to be the same as the your second expression.
2. Either in your dataset query or by adding a calculated field in your dataset properties, create a new year column (e.g. `FinalYear`) that evaluates to the actual year that you want to show (e.g. 2017 in the example above). You can then replace all references to `Fields!Year.Value` with `Fields!FinalYear.Value` including all sorting and grouping expressions.

Personally I would go for the second option and do this in the query if possible. It makes life much easier in the report design as there is little left to do.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I'll try it.  Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Hi Alan, well unfortunately I could not make it work.  I started over and simplified the layout and I finally got rid of the empty column.  Thank you again for your time and help.